# First app: Swift, Obj-C or React Native?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I have been trying to build my first app a couple of times, but life in general has not made it happen yet. :) Here I go again!

I've put a lot of thought into considering which language to aim at, since I know it will take a lot of time to master one of these languages, and so I don't want to spend years working on the wrong language.

I first and foremost want to develop my app for iOS, but if I could launch it on all platforms with one programming language that would of course be even better. :)

So, basically, my question is: Which language should I spend time learning?

I have followed a few tutorials in Swift, but then came React Native, which made me wonder, if that was the language to practice - as a shortcut to develop for multiple platforms. Also, I have been recommended using Obj-C, even after Swift was released.

One thing that made me second-guess React Native was the lack of tutorials for beginners, which there are plenty of for Swift and Obj-C.

Considerations, recommendations and tutorials for the language to choose would be most appreciated! :) It might be a question in itself, but some sort of a study plan for your recommended language would be amazing!

Comment: Adam, that comment doesn't really contribute with anything or consider the factors that I list above. A bit immature to say the least. Why would I write a question here about your considerations, if Google had the answer? But I'd like to hear your own considerations in regards to the question above! Thanks :)

Comment: You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before asking your question.

Comment: Yes ... but this is a "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"? This might be a more of a general question than a problem with a string of code. But it is practical and answerable, and it is based on an actual problem. Please see GuilhE's and zaph's answers for reference on how you could answer a question like this.

Comment: I wonder who thought this question is unclear and not useful; in regards to -1 above  ... :) I'm thinking a LOT of beginners considers this type of question very useful. And I can't see how it's unclear?! But maybe many beginners never get started, because they fear being ridiculed. This place is for everybody, also beginners. On the other hand, why do you waste time commenting beginner-questions, if your comment is not useful?

Comment: Adam, you are so childish. Why did you delete your initial, ridiculing comment?

Comment: Also, how can this question be "too broad"? I ask people to recommend one of three specific solutions. That is not very broad? It is a general question, but it is specific. Come on, guys, don't just play along with Adam. If you think this question is too broad, please explain why.

Comment: I didn't delete my comment. I guess it was deleted by moderator. Doesn't matter anymore, the question is already closed.

Comment: Well done, champ :) I know these beginner questions are just awful. Can't stand them. Have to be hidden away. "Not too broad you say, but a specific question about the choice between three programming languages that could really help a lot of beginners? Let's close it anyway!" Bravo.

Comment: If you are not happy with the rules, leave.

Comment: I'm happy with the rules. Not happy with 'superusers' who first ridicule the question, and then interpret a rule to his own liking. This question is useful (for beginners), it's clear and it's specific. How is it not following the rules? Too basic? That's not against the rules, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The initial comment which offended you was not Adam's words, but a prepared message which is put on there automatically as a result of his flagging the question as too broad or one that has no definitive answer, only opinions.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little surprised that this site has an automated comment which makes fun of people who spend time to post a serious question. Just because one or more thinks the question is too broad. If that is the case, then maybe the site should consider changing that approach. Just a formal, respectful comment would make more sense in my opinion. Why the ridicule? And why was the initial comment deleted, if it is an automated approach to questions being flagged?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well if you want a "one man band" solution C# should be your choice, why? Because cross-platform solutions like Xamarin and Unity. But in my opinion (I don't know if you're a developer) you should know more than one language and more importantly how iOS, Android, Windows Mobile, etc... SDK/API/Architecture works because even if you choose one language to deploy to more than one device you have to know who it works under the hood in a "native way" or you'll be doomed.
If you want to develop a game, Unity it's the answer, and by the way, it's C# too (and in this particularly case you don't have to look under the hood).
Google about Xamarin Forms and cross-platforms solutions pros and cons.
I'm not a cross-platform solution enthusiast, except for games (Unity). Hope it helps.
Take care.

ps: be good at one thing instead of reasonable in many ;)

Comment: Thanks, really helpful answer! I will look into it.
I do not work as a developer. I just like to code and have a few ideas for apps that I would like to develop. :)
Is it so that Unity also works with Swift/Obj-C?

Comment: Spend some time learning object-oriented languages such like Java and C# (more similar, Java for Android, C# for .NET, Unity, Xamarin) and Objective-C (iOS), and focus in one platform to begin with. Unity it's different, its in C# but it's IDE (Integrated development environment) and Engine abstracts you from "native code" and gets thing easier to achieve. It's only for games, not "common-apps"

Comment: Just looked briefly at Xamarin, and it looks really attractive! :) A little pricy.
So, if I'd like to start out building a simple app for iOS that allows the user to (1) type in integers, to (2) show colorful graphs based on calculations of these integers and dates (calendar), to (3) send the user push-messages, and to (4) save this data for use the next time the user opens the app, would Xamarin/C# be able to do all of this? (My guess is: yes! :))
Next, do you have any specific recommendations for a study plan for C# from absolute beginner level? Or tutorials and so?

Comment: In regards to my comment above, will the Indie-payment-solution at Xamarin be good for the app that I describe? I can see that it doesn't support Visual Studio, only Xamarin Studio (don't exactly know the difference).

Comment: The biggest "problems" with Xamarin is it's licenses to develop and the IDE (Xamarin Studio). Compared with Visual Studio (C#), IntelliJ (Java) or XCode (Objective-C), is light years behind. You can use Visual Studio to develop in Xamarin instead of Xamarin Studio (didn't know that about not being available in Indie-payment-solution). Yes you can achieve what you want, but honestly, I think you can forget Xamarin for now. Learn how to program for Android or iOS and get used to the chosen architecture and code libraries available. You don't have to pay for it like in Xamarin

Comment: Also, the libs available for Android and iOS are must vast and well tested and implemented. Regarding books and tutorials, I would google a bit and try to find some good user forums about the platform/language and you can start from there asking for some guidance. Regards ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks! :) And now I just started to think C# and Xamarin looked so attractive. ;) 
So, just to get it right: Even though I'd like to develop for both iOS and Android, and I have a fairly simple first app in mind, you still think I should focus on one platform to begin with?

Comment: Yes, until you feel comfortable making that simple app in one platform and maybe trying to do the same with the other platform (both in native code), I would leave Xamarin aside. And remember something very important: although Xamarin lets you code "once-to-many" this happens only using Xamarin Forms, and they are very limited, specially regarding the UI/UX. Because if you don't use Forms you'll be developing different type of codes, both in C#, but with complete different logic. That's not what you want in this particular case. It would be worthless using Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

You will find more support here with Objective-C or Swift.

If you know "C" Objective-C is probably easier to pickup.

If you know "C#" Swift will be closer. Keep in mind that Swift is a very large language.

Comment: Unfortunately I know neither C nor C#. I know a little Swift and a little JavaScript.

Comment: You surely meant "small". C++ is a "large" language.